# How to merge multiple variables based on their names text with a specific pattern in R?

Tags: r, variables, merge

My question is simplified.
I have multiple variables with a specific pattern in the names such as below:

```
Name1<- rep("AA",3)        
Name2<- rep("BB",3)
Name3<- rep("CC",3) 
Name4<- rep("DD",3)
```

I want to select two of that, for example:

```
x<- c(2,3)
y<- paste0("Name",x)
```

But it returns the names of variables:

```
"Name1" "Name2"
```

I want the content of variables like below:

```
"AA" "AA" "AA" "BB" "BB" "BB"
```

Comment: It may be useful to tag the programming language you are working in.

Comment: Maybe `c(Name1, Name2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is slightly unclear, but the following is a proposed solution to create a vector like `c(2,3)` to get the Name values.

```
Name1<- rep("AA",3)        
Name2<- rep("BB",3)
Name3<- rep("CC",3) 
Name4<- rep("DD",3)

all_names <- list(Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4)

x<-c(2,3)

unlist(all_names[x])
```

Results:

```
> unlist(all_names[x])
[1] "BB" "BB" "BB" "CC" "CC" "CC"
```